# How can I deploy a reveal.js app to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I am trying to deploy a reveal.js application to Heroku. Reveal.js runs on node via `grunt connect` command. The app also requires ruby for compiling assets on-the-fly. Locally, I can run the app by using `grunt serve`.

Initially, because of compass being a dependency of `grunt watch`, Heroku only detected the Gemfile and assumed I was running a ruby app. I used the nodejs custom buildpack to force Heroku to see it as a nodejs app.

Procfile contains

```
web: grunt serve
```

Log shows

```
 2013-06-17T13:51:56.187012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"
```

`heroku ps` shows nothing either. I can run "heroku run grunt serve" successfully, and I have modified the default Gruntfile.js that comes with reveal to accept process.env i.e.

```
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: process.env.PORT || 8000,
      base: '.'
    } 
  }
}
```

As a last attempt, I tried using the Heroku-nodejs-grunt build pack (https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) which will run a grunt task on deploy to compile assets. Still no luck, `heroku logs --tail` still shows no process running. Exploring with `heroku run` reveals that grunt is available, and the `grunt serve` command successfully executes.

When starting to use the new grunt build pack I got an error with the above Gruntfile.js saying "process" is undefined. I switched the port to 0.

> The port on which the webserver will respond. The task will fail if
>   the specified port is already in use. You can use the special values 0
>   or '?' to use a system-assigned port.

Didn't work, tried "?", didn't work (still no web process and `heroku restart` doesn't do anything)

I can't figure out how to get Heroku to use grunt serve as my main web server process!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to make it work using nodejs and expressJs.

By following the heroku "getting started with nodejs", I was able to get a working webapp with expressjs and by declaring this in the web.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

With this you serve everything from / statically.

You have the sources here: https://github.com/MichaelBitard/revealjs_heroku and a working example here: http://murmuring-cove-4212.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This works great and is detailed in a sitepoint post as well. If you follow Michael's note, just ensure that you have added Express as a dependency in your package.json.
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-slick-html-presentations-using-reveal-js/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that by default `grunt serve` binds to `localhost`. For it to work you will need to do a couple of small changes to `reveal.js`:

First add `grunt-cli` as a `devDependency`:

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 10489bb..4c58442 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -36,6 +36,7 @@
     "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.8.0",
     "grunt-autoprefixer": "~1.0.1",
     "grunt-zip": "~0.7.0",
+    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
     "grunt": "~0.4.0",
     "node-sass": "~0.9.3"
   },
```

Then add a `hostname` parameter to `grunt` that will be used to bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.

```
diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index 3e67b9f..b2bfc47 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 /* global module:false */
 module.exports = function(grunt) {
+   var hostname = grunt.option('hostname') || 'localhost';
    var port = grunt.option('port') || 8000;
    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
@@ -94,6 +95,7 @@ module.exports = function(grunt) {
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
+                   hostname: hostname,
                    port: port,
                    base: '.',
                    livereload: true,
```

Now you can create a `Procfile` with the following contents to deploy to Heroku:

```
web: npm install && node_modules/.bin/grunt serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

I have created a [PR](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/1129) for the needed changes to `reveal.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently with express v~4.13.3 `express.logger()` is deprecated and is not included with the express package. To solve this I had to import the dependency `morgan`.

My `web.js` file ended up being the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server started on ' + port);
});
```

As well, I needed to update my package.json to include the morgan lib. My dependencies in the file works with:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.13.3",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "mustache": "~2.2.1",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7"
},
...
```